# Inject JavaScript to website

Tags: javascript, c#, chromium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm trying to inject JavaScript code to a website and run this function:

```
    String js = "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
    "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
    "script.text = \"function myFunction() { " +
       "return 'test method';" +

    "}\";" +
    "(document.head || document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);";
    chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(js);
    chromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("myFunction();");
```

It's a simple code that return text.

When i try to inject it and call `myFunction` i get this error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined @ about:blank:1:0
```

Comment: shouldn't you just add the function definition to the browser?
i mean `chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("function myFunction(){return 'foo';}")`;  then you should be able to execute the script afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `Async` methods could it be that `myFunction` isn't yet defined but will be soon?

Try this:

```
chromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("setTimeout(myFunction, 100);");
```